# Как сделать из картинки ссылку?

Tags: html, css

Не получается сделать из картинки ссылку ! Картинка сделана как сликслайдер , при приминении тега (A) к картинке она прападает! Код прикладываю ниже :

```css
.slider {

  // .slider__item

  &__item {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 70px 10px;
  
    a{
      
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      
    }

  }

  // .slider__item-title

  &__item-title {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 10px 0 7px;
  }

  // .slider__item-text

  &__item-text {
  
  }
}
.filter {
}

.a{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">

            
            <div class="slider__item filter">
              <img src="img/Hero.png" alt="text">
                <div class="slider__item-title">My First Project</div>
                
                
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">

               <img src="img/Hero.png" alt="">
            
                <div class="slider__item-title">My Firt Project</div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item ">
                <div class="img__img">
              <a href=""><img src="img/Hero.png" alt=""></a></div>
                
                <div class="slider__item-title">My Firt Project</div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
                <img src="img/Hero.png" alt="">
                <div class="slider__item-title">My Firt Project</div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: а блок "slider__item" не вариант полностью обернуть в ссылку?

Comment: Обернул , теперь проблемма в том что на Chrome картинка пропала а в firefox все работает ...

Comment: скиньте ссылку на проект, или закиньте файлы в песочницу, чтобы посмотреть что у вас происходит

Comment: https://github.com/pologenki/My-Projects/tree/master/My%20CV  файлы на gite

Comment: Посмотрел, все работает без проблем, и в хроме и firefox,  вот скрин: https://pastenow.ru/b0cf4041dc1d349b108ecbbd5f00825f

Возможно нужно просто почистить кэш.